# Android list view Right / Left swipes like call logs

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-animation, swipe

I have an Android application in which there is List View Like this one

[image]

Now I want to perform two different activities on right/Left swipe of the List Items in the same way How native call log works

Right Swipe of list

[image]

I want this type of swipes. Can anyone know how to make it happen. Basically I wan to implement `SimpleOnGestureListener`.

I have read a post answered by **sir gav** [Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection) and after that I am successful in implementing left swipe and right swipe detection but the only thing I am not getting on which List Item the swipe has occurred.

**Update** 24 May 2013

Now I am able to detect swipe action using this code --

**SwipeDetector.java**

```
/**
 * Class swipe detection to View
 */
public class SwipeDetector implements View.OnTouchListener {

    public static enum Action {
        LR, // Left to right
        RL, // Right to left
        TB, // Top to bottom
        BT, // Bottom to top
        None // Action not found
    }

    private static final int HORIZONTAL_MIN_DISTANCE = 30; // The minimum
    // distance for
    // horizontal swipe
    private static final int VERTICAL_MIN_DISTANCE = 80; // The minimum distance
    // for vertical
    // swipe
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY; // Coordinates
    private Action mSwipeDetected = Action.None; // Last action

    public boolean swipeDetected() {
        return mSwipeDetected != Action.None;
    }

    public Action getAction() {
        return mSwipeDetected;
    }

    /**
     * Swipe detection
     */@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
                return false; // allow other events like Click to be processed
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            {
                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();

                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;

                // horizontal swipe detection
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > HORIZONTAL_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // left or right
                    if (deltaX < 0) {

                        mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (deltaX > 0) {

                        mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
                        return true;
                    }
                } else

                // vertical swipe detection
                if (Math.abs(deltaY) > VERTICAL_MIN_DISTANCE) {
                    // top or down
                    if (deltaY < 0) {

                        mSwipeDetected = Action.TB;
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (deltaY > 0) {

                        mSwipeDetected = Action.BT;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now use it with your ListView in this fashion

```
    // Set the touch listener
    final SwipeDetector swipeDetector = new SwipeDetector();
    lv.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);
```

In your `setOnItemClickListener` you can detect the swipe events like these

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

        if (swipeDetector.swipeDetected()) {
            if (swipeDetector.getAction() == SwipeDetector.Action.LR) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Left to right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            if (swipeDetector.getAction() == SwipeDetector.Action.RL) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Right to left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
});
```

But still I am not able to animate the swipe like these:

[image]

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833504/simple-swipe-gesture-to-activity-tutorial

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal have u got the solution for this

Comment: @Nikhil Agrwal: I am looking for the same , have you got any solution for this ??

Answer (score 1):

you can use Fragments for this requirement. Use FragmentPagerAdapter and overide getItem(int position) which will return you the fragment. 
set the adapter to viewPager and in the setOnPageChangeListener you can have the logic for calling different fragment.

Shrishail