# is it possible to define actions to list item without entering the list item?? - Android

Tags: android, listview

I am creating an android application including vehicle information to list view. when clicking the list item it displayed information about the vehicle. Now I want to add Delete and Edit vehicle information without entering the list item. is it possible to add double click and long click for list item for these two events(delete and edit actions) without entering the list item?

Comment: Yes, You can add `onItemLongClickListner` to your `ListView` ( link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html )

Comment: is it possible to double click or something another action to list item to give edit action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following pattern: swiping or long clicking will reveal additional views in your list item.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017988/android-list-view-right-left-swipes-like-call-logs) will be a decent starting point for you.

Also [this](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) library looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

You will need index number of element in array to delete it from datasource.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if(list.contains(3)){//check if the list contains the element
        list.get(list.indexOf(3));//get the element by passing the index of the element
    }
```

About Your second question: Yes it is possible to delete item on LongPress

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemLongClick((AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
myAdapter.removeItemAt(pos); // you need to implement this method
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
));
```

Comment: is it possible to double click list item?? (for edit action)

Comment: yes everything is possible mate. its programming