# Implement Swipe in ListView

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, swipe

I want to implement Swipe in ListView like in Samsung Android Phones calling function

I have a list shown in below image :

[image]

Now when I swipe right side at some distance of swipe from left i.e 25% distance it just changed background, like call function in Samsung device or like SwipeListView:

[image]

need solution for this.

Comment: Have you got any solution of it or anyone don't have any solution?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. Please post your code.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321016/android-listview-slide-left-right-like-samsung-contact-listview) is relevant what you want. You can try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13312058/719212) and update your question if there are any problems.

Comment: @Jayesh How can anyone tell you how to achieve this unless you post the code you currently have? Until you post your code I am unable to provide a solution.

Comment: @Jayesh So you have no code and the solution would be to implement the features you requested in the demo source? I'm fairly sure that's not how StackOverflow works. You say "I have a list shown in below image", so why have you not posted this code? Your images are very different to the demo.

Comment: @tpbapp: dude, I post these images from Iphone application, If I have implemented this in android then why should I posted this issue here

Comment: @Jayesh I see, no worries please see revised answer below. Hopefully this is closer to what you are needing.

Comment: @tpbapp: I don't want calling , but I want animation something like implemented in samsung android phone like image shown in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983739/swipe-effect-like-in-samsung-phone-calling-and-message

Comment: @Jayesh So when you swipe left you need it to pull out a green button which can then be pressed to call or do whatever else you need to do?

Comment: @tpbapp: yes I want to delete(dismiss) row in which I will swipe and this is implemented in SwipeListView Demo of github, swiping left or right with dismiss/reveal function is implemented in github demo

Comment: @tpbapp: now I want that when user swipe right background color  is changed with imageview(of delete) and Text Delete, so that user can see that raw is deleted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this code :

### main.xml file

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

---

### raw.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="ABC"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/delete_lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#55ff0000"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Deleting..."
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

### MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import de.timroes.swipetodismiss.SwipeDismissList;
import de.timroes.swipetodismiss.SwipeDismissList.SwipeDirection;
import de.timroes.swipetodismiss.SwipeDismissList.UndoMode;
import de.timroes.swipetodismiss.SwipeDismissList.Undoable;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> listData;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
SwipeListAdapter listAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    listData = new ArrayList<String>();
    listData.add("item 1");
    listData.add("item 2");
    listData.add("item 3");
    listData.add("item 4");
    listData.add("item 5");
    listData.add("item 6");
    listData.add("item 7");
    listData.add("item 8");
    listData.add("item 9");
    listData.add("item 10");
    listData.add("item 11");
    listData.add("item 12");
    listData.add("item 13");
    listData.add("item 14");
    listData.add("item 15");
    listData.add("item 16");
    listData.add("item 17");

    listAdapter = new SwipeListAdapter(MainActivity.this);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    SwipeDismissList.OnDismissCallback callback = new SwipeDismissList.OnDismissCallback() {
        @Override
        public Undoable onDismiss(AbsListView listView, int position) {
            View view = (View) listView.getChildAt(0);

            view.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(200).translationX(10);
            listAdapter.remove(position);
            return null;
        }
    };

    UndoMode mode = SwipeDismissList.UndoMode.SINGLE_UNDO;

    SwipeDismissList swipeList = new SwipeDismissList(listView, callback,
            mode);
    swipeList.setSwipeDirection(SwipeDirection.END);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

class SwipeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;

    public SwipeListAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private void remove(int pos) {
        listData.remove(pos);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                        R.layout.raw, null);
            }
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.name);
            textView.setText(listData.get(position));

            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50);
            layout.setLayoutParams(params);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}

}
```

### SwipeDismissList.java

```
import static com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper.setAlpha;
import static com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewHelper.setTranslationX;
import static com.nineoldandroids.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.animate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.VelocityTracker;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator;
import com.nineoldandroids.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator;


public final class SwipeDismissList implements View.OnTouchListener {

// Cached ViewConfiguration and system-wide constant values
private int mSlop;
private int mMinFlingVelocity;
private int mMaxFlingVelocity;
private long mAnimationTime;

// Fixed properties
private AbsListView mListView;
private OnDismissCallback mCallback;
private int mViewWidth = 1; // 1 and not 0 to prevent dividing by zero

// Transient properties
private SortedSet<PendingDismissData> mPendingDismisses = new TreeSet<PendingDismissData>();
private int mDismissAnimationRefCount = 0;
private float mDownX;
private boolean mSwiping;
private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker;
private int mDownPosition;
private View mDownView;
private boolean mPaused;
private float mDensity;
private boolean mSwipeDisabled;

private UndoMode mMode;
private List<Undoable> mUndoActions;
private Handler mHandler;

private PopupWindow mUndoPopup;
private TextView mUndoText;
private Button mUndoButton;

private SwipeDirection mSwipeDirection = SwipeDirection.BOTH;
private int mAutoHideDelay = 5000;
private String mDeleteString = "Item deleted";
private String mDeleteMultipleString = "%d items deleted";
private boolean mTouchBeforeAutoHide = true;

private int mDelayedMsgId;

View frontView;
View backView;
RelativeLayout layout ;


public enum UndoMode {

    SINGLE_UNDO,


    MULTI_UNDO,


    COLLAPSED_UNDO
};


public enum SwipeDirection {

    BOTH,

    START,

    END
}


public interface OnDismissCallback {


    Undoable onDismiss(AbsListView listView, int position);
}


public abstract static class Undoable {


    public String getTitle() {
        return null;
    }


    public abstract void undo();


    public void discard() { }

}


public SwipeDismissList(AbsListView listView, OnDismissCallback callback) {
    this(listView, callback, UndoMode.SINGLE_UNDO);
}


public SwipeDismissList(AbsListView listView, OnDismissCallback callback, UndoMode mode) {

    if(listView == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("listview must not be null.");
    }

    mHandler = new HideUndoPopupHandler();
    mListView = listView;
    mCallback = callback;
    mMode = mode;

    ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(listView.getContext());
    mSlop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
    mMinFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();
    mMaxFlingVelocity = vc.getScaledMaximumFlingVelocity();
    mAnimationTime = listView.getContext().getResources().getInteger(
        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

    mDensity = mListView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    // -- Load undo popup --
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mListView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.undo_popup, null);
    mUndoButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.undo);
    mUndoButton.setOnClickListener(new UndoHandler());
    mUndoButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // If user tabs "undo" button, reset delay time to remove popup
            mDelayedMsgId++;
            return false;
        }
    });
    mUndoText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);

    mUndoPopup = new PopupWindow(v);
    mUndoPopup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.fade_animation);
    // Get scren width in dp and set width respectively
    int xdensity = (int)(mListView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / mDensity);
    if(xdensity < 300) {
        mUndoPopup.setWidth((int)(mDensity * 280));
    } else if(xdensity < 350) {
        mUndoPopup.setWidth((int)(mDensity * 300));
    } else if(xdensity < 500) {
        mUndoPopup.setWidth((int)(mDensity * 330));
    } else {
        mUndoPopup.setWidth((int)(mDensity * 450));
    }
    mUndoPopup.setHeight((int)(mDensity * 56));
    // -- END Load undo popu --

    listView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    listView.setOnScrollListener(this.makeScrollListener());

    switch(mode) {
        case SINGLE_UNDO:
            mUndoActions = new ArrayList<Undoable>(1);
            break;
        default:
            mUndoActions = new ArrayList<Undoable>(10);
            break;
    }

}


private void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mPaused = !enabled;
}

public void setAutoHideDelay(int delay) {
    mAutoHideDelay = delay;
}


public void setSwipeDirection(SwipeDirection direction) {
    mSwipeDirection = direction;
}


public void setUndoString(String msg) {
    mDeleteString = msg;
}


public void setUndoMultipleString(String msg) {
    mDeleteMultipleString = msg;
}


public void setRequireTouchBeforeDismiss(boolean require) {
    mTouchBeforeAutoHide = require;
}


public void discardUndo() {
    for(Undoable undoable : mUndoActions) {
        undoable.discard();
    }
    mUndoActions.clear();
    mUndoPopup.dismiss();
}


private AbsListView.OnScrollListener makeScrollListener() {
    return new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
            setEnabled(scrollState != AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }
    };
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (this.mSwipeDisabled) {
        return false;
    }

    if (mViewWidth < 2) {
        mViewWidth = mListView.getWidth();
    }

    switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            if (mPaused) {
                return false;
            }

            // TODO: ensure this is a finger, and set a flag

            // Find the child view that was touched (perform a hit test)
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            int childCount = mListView.getChildCount();
            int[] listViewCoords = new int[2];
            mListView.getLocationOnScreen(listViewCoords);
            int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX() - listViewCoords[0];
            int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY() - listViewCoords[1];
            View child;
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                child = mListView.getChildAt(i);
                child.getHitRect(rect);
                if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
                    mDownView = child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (mDownView != null) {
                mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                mDownPosition = mListView.getPositionForView(mDownView);

                mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            }
            view.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return true;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
                break;
            }

            float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);
            float velocityX = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity());
            float velocityY = Math.abs(mVelocityTracker.getYVelocity());
            boolean dismiss = false;
            boolean dismissRight = false;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mViewWidth / 2 && mSwiping) {
                dismiss = true;
                dismissRight = deltaX > 0;
            } else if (mMinFlingVelocity <= velocityX && velocityX <= mMaxFlingVelocity
                && velocityY < velocityX && mSwiping && isDirectionValid(mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity())
                && deltaX >= mViewWidth * 0.2f) {
                dismiss = true;
                dismissRight = mVelocityTracker.getXVelocity() > 0;
            }
            if (dismiss) {
                // dismiss
                final View downView = frontView; // mDownView gets null'd before animation ends
                final int downPosition = mDownPosition;
                ++mDismissAnimationRefCount;
                animate(frontView)
                    .translationX(dismissRight ? mViewWidth : -mViewWidth)
                    .alpha(0)
                    .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override 
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        performDismiss(downView, downPosition);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                // cancel
                animate(frontView)
                    .translationX(0)
                    .alpha(1)
                    .setDuration(mAnimationTime)
                    .setListener(null);
            }
            mVelocityTracker = null;
            mDownX = 0;
            mDownView = null;
            mDownPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
            mSwiping = false;

            if(backView != null) {
                backView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                frontView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setTranslationX(frontView, 0);

                layout = null;
                backView = null;
                frontView = null;
            }
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if(mTouchBeforeAutoHide && mUndoPopup.isShowing()) {    
                // Send a delayed message to hide popup
                mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(mDelayedMsgId), 
                    mAutoHideDelay);
            }

            if (mVelocityTracker == null || mPaused) {
                break;
            }

            mVelocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);
            float deltaX = motionEvent.getRawX() - mDownX;
            // Only start swipe in correct direction
            if(isDirectionValid(deltaX)) {
                if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mSlop) {
                    mSwiping = true;
                    mListView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                    // Cancel ListView's touch (un-highlighting the item)
                    MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
                    cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL
                        | (motionEvent.getActionIndex()
                        << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT));
                    mListView.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
                }
            } else {
                mDownX = motionEvent.getRawX();
                deltaX = 0;
            }

            if(layout == null) {
                layout = (RelativeLayout) mDownView;
                frontView = layout.getChildAt(0);
                backView = layout.getChildAt(1);
            }

            if(deltaX > 50) {
                backView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (mSwiping) {
                setTranslationX(frontView, deltaX);
                setAlpha(frontView, Math.max(0f, Math.min(1f,
                    1f - 2f * Math.abs(deltaX) / mViewWidth)));
                return true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


private boolean isDirectionValid(float deltaX) {

    int rtlSign = 1;
    // On API level 17 and above, check if we are in a Right-To-Left layout
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        if(mListView.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
            rtlSign = -1;
        }
    }

    // Check if swipe has been done in the corret direction
    switch(mSwipeDirection) {
        default:
        case BOTH:
            return true;
        case START:
            return rtlSign * deltaX < 0;
        case END:
            return rtlSign * deltaX > 0;
    }

}

class PendingDismissData implements Comparable<PendingDismissData> {

    public int position;
    public View view;

    public PendingDismissData(int position, View view) {
        this.position = position;
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PendingDismissData other) {
        // Sort by descending position
        return other.position - position;
    }
}

private void performDismiss(final View dismissView, final int dismissPosition) {
    // Animate the dismissed list item to zero-height and fire the dismiss callback when
    // all dismissed list item animations have completed. This triggers layout on each animation
    // frame; in the future we may want to do something smarter and more performant.

    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = dismissView.getLayoutParams();
    final int originalHeight = dismissView.getHeight();

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, 1).setDuration(mAnimationTime);

    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            --mDismissAnimationRefCount;
            if (mDismissAnimationRefCount == 0) {
                // No active animations, process all pending dismisses.

                for(PendingDismissData dismiss : mPendingDismisses) {
                    if(mMode == UndoMode.SINGLE_UNDO) {
                        for(Undoable undoable : mUndoActions) {
                            undoable.discard();
                        }
                        mUndoActions.clear();
                    }
                    Undoable undoable = mCallback.onDismiss(mListView, dismiss.position);
                    if(undoable != null) {
                        mUndoActions.add(undoable);
                    }
                    mDelayedMsgId++;
                }

                if(!mUndoActions.isEmpty()) {
                    changePopupText();
                    changeButtonLabel();

                    // Show undo popup
                    mUndoPopup.showAtLocation(mListView, 
                        Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM,
                        0, (int)(mDensity * 15));

                    // Queue the dismiss only if required
                    if(!mTouchBeforeAutoHide) { 
                        // Send a delayed message to hide popup
                        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(mDelayedMsgId), 
                            mAutoHideDelay);
                    }
                }

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp;
                for (PendingDismissData pendingDismiss : mPendingDismisses) {
                    // Reset view presentation
                    setAlpha(pendingDismiss.view, 1f);
                    setTranslationX(pendingDismiss.view, 0);
                    lp = pendingDismiss.view.getLayoutParams();
                    lp.height = originalHeight;
                    pendingDismiss.view.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }

                mPendingDismisses.clear();
            }
        }
    });

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            lp.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            dismissView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
    });

    mPendingDismisses.add(new PendingDismissData(dismissPosition, dismissView));
    animator.start();
}


private void changePopupText() {
    String msg = "";
    if(mUndoActions.size() > 1 && mDeleteMultipleString != null) {
        msg = String.format(mDeleteMultipleString, mUndoActions.size());
    } else if(mUndoActions.size() >= 1) {
        // Set title from single undoable or when no multiple deletion string
        // is given
        if(mUndoActions.get(mUndoActions.size() - 1).getTitle() != null) {
            msg = mUndoActions.get(mUndoActions.size() - 1).getTitle();
        } else {
            msg = mDeleteString;
        }
    }
    mUndoText.setText(msg);
}

private void changeButtonLabel() {
    String msg;
    if(mUndoActions.size() > 1 && mMode == UndoMode.COLLAPSED_UNDO) {
        msg = mListView.getResources().getString(R.string.undoall);
    } else {
        msg = mListView.getResources().getString(R.string.undo);
    }
    mUndoButton.setText(msg);
}

/**
 * Takes care of undoing a dismiss. This will be added as a 
 * {@link View.OnClickListener} to the undo button in the undo popup.
 */
private class UndoHandler implements View.OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!mUndoActions.isEmpty()) {
            switch(mMode) {
                case SINGLE_UNDO:
                    mUndoActions.get(0).undo();
                    mUndoActions.clear();
                    break;
                case COLLAPSED_UNDO:
                    Collections.reverse(mUndoActions);
                    for(Undoable undo : mUndoActions) {
                        undo.undo();    
                    }
                    mUndoActions.clear();
                    break;
                case MULTI_UNDO:
                    mUndoActions.get(mUndoActions.size() - 1).undo();
                    mUndoActions.remove(mUndoActions.size() - 1);
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Dismiss dialog or change text
        if(mUndoActions.isEmpty()) {
            mUndoPopup.dismiss();
        } else {
            changePopupText();
            changeButtonLabel();
        }

        mDelayedMsgId++;

    }

}

/**
 * Handler used to hide the undo popup after a special delay.
 */
private class HideUndoPopupHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(msg.what == mDelayedMsgId) {
            // Call discard on any element
            for(Undoable undo : mUndoActions) {
                undo.discard();
            }
            mUndoActions.clear();
            mUndoPopup.dismiss();
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Enable/disable swipe.
 */
public void setSwipeDisabled(boolean disabled) {
    this.mSwipeDisabled = disabled;
}
  }
```

---

### [image]

enjoy!

Comment: where is undopopup.xml ?

Comment: Hey! jitendra : please remove it and its related code,its for my use.

Answer (score 3):

Use a ListView extension such as [android-swipelistview](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview).

You may also need to refer to the [demo](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview-sample) source. Instructions for setting up the demo can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689572/implementing-47degree-android-swipelistview-for-swipping-android-listviewitem).

To make a phone call when the user swipes left, add the below code to the instance of SwipeListView:

*src > activities > SwipeListViewExampleActivity.java > onCreate()*

```
swipeListView.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
        if(!toRight) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));    
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

For swipe right you can set it to dismiss which should be sufficient for what you are trying to achieve.

*res > layout > swipe-list-view-activity.xml > SwipeListView*

```
swipe:swipeActionRight="dismiss"
```

Comment: than what if he is fresher...?

Comment: @Jayesh as I previosuly stated it is not clear what you are trying to achieve and you haven't posted any source code to give an indication of where you're at, which is necessary in order to provide a solution.

Comment: downvoted since the links are dead now

Answer (score 1):

you can use this library https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView An Android ListView with enhanced functionality (e.g. Swipe To Dismiss or Undo).